# Symfony 4 serialize entity with relationship unexpected value NULL

Tags: symfony, serialization, entity, entity-relationship, symfony4

I have ManyToOne relationship between Posts and User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User\User")
 */
private $author;
```

After I obtain response form my endpoint which looks like this:

```
array:2 [
  "message" => "OK"
  "data" => array:1 [
    0 => Post {#6077
      -id: 1
      -title: "sda"
      -teaser: "asdj"
      -content: "asd"
      -createdDateTime: DateTime @1517078058 {#6075
        date: 2018-01-27 18:34:18.0 UTC (+00:00)
      }
      -deletedDateTime: null
      -author: User {#6294
        +__isInitialized__: false
        -id: 1
        -firstName: null
        -lastName: null
        -email: null
        -activationCode: null
        -isActive: null
        -createdDateTime: null
        -deletedDateTime: null
         …2
      }
      -statusId: false
    }
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to serialize it to JSON. Perviously(Symfony 3) there was a problem with Circular References which I managed to solve but this is little bit different.

I keep getting 500 response with exception:

```
NotNormalizableValueException
An unexpected value could not be normalized: NULL
```

If I remove relationship between entities it's fine so it's clearly the problem.

It's treating related object as something that cannot be normalized. For some reason. Not sure why it's happening. Didn't find anything in the docs on that.

Anything I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have solved my problem. I went to:

```
/vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php
```

After little investigation I was able to find out that normalizer is falling over PHP RESOURCE.

It turned out that I had one field of VARBINARY type in my User table. According to [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#binary) that type is translated to PHP resource.

Conclusion: Symfony serialization does not have any problems with serializing entity and related child entities. It is simply not capable of normalizing resource type of data.

I think that's something worth remembering.

Comment: Glad you figured out!

Comment: Could You share how did You solve this case, anyway ?

Comment: I have described that in my answer. There is nothing more to that. Unless you are asking about something else? What else would you like to know?

Comment: Same thing for `blob` type - changed to `text` after having same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would need some more info to help you. What serializer are you using, the Symfony one? How are you loading the serializer? Whatever it may be, the error is clear: the normalizer of the serializer you are using does not know what to do when finds a null field. My guess is that you are loading just one normalizer (of the around 5 available) to your serializer as it is shown in the official Symfony Serializer docs.

Comment: I confirm : some serializer like the JMS one have to been configured to serialize null values, using `setSerializeNull(true)` method on serializer instance.

Comment: Alright I need to be more specific: So I am using native Symfony serializer. Only difference is that I've build service around it so I can have shortcut methods like serialize2Json(). I am loading ObjectNormalizer which according to docs is "most powerful" and usually it's more then enough. Just now I've loaded all 7 normalizers available in the docs. Didn't make a difference, error remains still the same. In S3 I had only object normalizer and it was enough. Post object I'm pulling from DB has only one value, rest is null and it's fine(if without relationship, not the case presented in post).

Comment: What kind of loading configuration do you have for your entities in Doctrine? Double check that are "lazy_loaded". What you are getting as your Post object is the Doctrine proxy. The ObjectNormalizer should load that thing without a problem because it uses PropertyAccess, but only if you have configured your entities to be lazy loaded.

Comment: If I am not mistaken by default Doctrine uses lazy load. So that's what it is. However I have already tried to set user relationship in every possible configuration which is fetch="LAZY", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", fetch="EAGER" but nothing seems to be working. I got this feeling it's some kind of strange bug with symfony serializer. However it was working in pervious verison so not sure now. Do you need any additional piece of information?